# Passing less argument to function then defined in Python

Tags: python, function, args

If I have a function with multiple functions, let say, calculating an area or adding three numbers.
The user chose 1 for calculating area and 2 for adding numbers via input

```
def func_calculate(numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, userChoise):
    if userChoise == "1":
        calculate Area
        do something
    if userChoise == "2":
        calculate addition
        do something
```

userChoise is the input from user

If user wants to calculate area there is only two arguments to the function instead of three, if user wants to make an addition.

So, finally to the question...
What is the most appropriate way to handle it?

When I call the function, when the user wants to calculate area, should I just set the numberThree variable to zero or something or is it a more "right" way do do it?

```
if userChoie == "1":    
    inputNumberOne = input(...
    inputNumberTwo = input(...
    inputNumberThree == 0 
    func_calculate(inputNumberOne, inputNumberTwo, inputNumberThree, userChoise)
```

Comment: Such distinct functions should be different functions: one to calculate an area, one to calculate the sum of three numbers.

Comment: Note: `inputNumberThree == 0` is not an assignment, but a comparison, and most likely will result in an error, since `inputNumberThree` is not yet defined at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't to perform multiple operations than it is good to have different functions for different operations

```
choice = input("what user want's to do")

if choice == 1:
     add()
elif choice == 2: 
     multiply()
```

and than take arguments from user for that operations like

```
def add():
      num1 = input("num1")
      num2 = input("num2")
      num3 = input("num3")
      print(num1 + num2 + num3)
```

and similarly for other operations

But if you don't wan't to have multiple functions the you can do

```
def func(choice):
    #choice is the integer which user opted
    if choice == 1:
          num1 = input("num1")
          num2 = input("num2")
          num3 = input("num3")
          print(num1 + num2 + num3)
    elif choice == 2:
          .........
```

Comment: It is maybe a better way to have different functions for different operations. It is maybe easier to read the code also. 
Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: yeah it makes your code more readable and clean. if answer worked for you, you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to this problem will be to have multiple functions, each with a specific role. You can make two separate functions `calculate_area()` and `add_numbers()`. Then, you can simply check the input and call these functions like this:

```py
userChoice = input("Enter choice: ")
if userChoice == "1":
    inputNumberOne = input("Enter number 1: ")
    inputNumberTwo = input("Enter number 2: ")
    calculate_area(inputNumberOne, inputNumberTwo)
elif userChoice == "2":
    inputNumberOne = input("Enter number 1: ")
    inputNumberTwo = input("Enter number 2: ")
    inputNumberThree = input("Enter number 3: ")
    add_numbers(inputNumberOne, inputNumberTwo, inputNumberThree)
```

Comment: Maybe it is a better way to have two or more functions, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use only one function with a variable number of parameters, you could use *args as argument. For example:

```
def funct_calculate(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        Calculate Area
    else:
        Addition

funct_calculate(radius,pi)
funct_calculate(number1,number2,number3)
```